# What is wrong with this concatenation function in C?

Tags: c, string, concatenation

this is part of a homework assignment using structs and I can't seem to understand this one function. The function is string_t *concat (string_t *s1, string_t *s2) and it returns the new string struct. This is what I have so far, and it crashes the compiler whenever it's reached. The program compiles but, "file".exe has stopped working error comes up when executing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
typedef struct string{ //String struct (in .h file)

char *line;
int length;

} string_t;


string_t* concat(string_t *s1, string_t *s2) { //actual function (in .c)

int len1, len2;
len1 = length(s1);
len2 = length(s2);

int i, j, s;

string_t *newStr;
newStr = (string_t*)malloc(sizeof(string_t)*2);


for (i = 0; i<len1; i++) {
    *((newStr->line)+i) = *((s1->line)+i);
    }

for (j=0; j<len2; j++) {
    *((newStr->line)+(i+j)) = *((s2->line)+j);
    }

*((newStr->line)+(i+j))='\0';

return newStr;

}



concat(s1, s2); //tests function
```

Comment: I'd suggest you use size_t for your string.length

Comment: have you googled strncpy and strcat? Are you allowed to use std functions?

Comment: No, I cannot use any provided functions.

Comment: @user2041197 I'm assuming `malloc()` is exempt from that statement.

Comment: who provided malloc? :-) j/k

Comment: I meant any provided string functions lol.

Comment: @WhozCraig, ha you are quick, I was thinking the same thing :-)

Comment: @user2041197 what about `realloc()` ? Is that ok?

Comment: When I try to test it I do s3 = concat(s1,s2) where s3 is a string_t* and I get an error saying assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast. any ideas?

Comment: @user2041197, I'd also suggest concat(const string_t* s1, const string_t* s2)

Comment: @WhozCraig Not if the lecturer wants the OP to reimplement malloc/realloc using static storage duration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
newStr = (string_t*)malloc(sizeof(string_t)*2);
```

You allocate memory for `newStr` but you don't allocate memory for `newStr->line`. Try something like:

```
newStr = malloc(sizeof *newStr);
newStr->line = malloc(s1->length + s2->length + 1);
```

---

Side note: `*((newStr->line)+i)` can be written as `newStr->line[i]`.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the second part, but our professor does not allow us to use indices, just pointer arithmetic

Comment: @user2041197 :( Who pays these people ?

Comment: I did what you said, but when I try to test it I do s3 = concat(s1,s2) where s3 is a string_t* and I get an error saying assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Likewise, you can lose the `strlen()` invokes (assuming you've been wise in ensuring your `.length` member is accurate).

Comment: I second that, I hadn't noticed there was a `length` field.

Comment: Heh. fix that and save me the hassle of writing an answer =P (I'll upvote regardless).

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not after the rep, I've enough. But I did edit since it was the right and obvious thing :-)

Comment: Oh I know, I wasn't up-voting to toss the rep (its somewhat pointless by now for you). But it does help make the answer stand out as being applicable.

Comment: Please consider [not casting the return value of `malloc()`, in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, here's a way to cat without that ugly ptr math syntax:

```
char* dest = newStr->line;

const char* src = s1->line;
while (*src)
{
  *dest = *src;
  ++dest;
  ++src;
}

src = s2->line;
while (*src)
{
  *dest = *src;
  ++dest;
  ++src;
}

*dest = '\0';
```

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, I do not like the post increment operators in C because there is a temporary that is created.  Most of the time it is more clear and obvious (IMHO) to use the preincrement operator almost exclusively.  If you like having to human-parse looking for all the possible craziness that the programmer can pack into one line, then there is absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, and I also agree it does work, I just wouldn't use it in my own code that I write.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, also that wouldn't quite work for the first loop because it would insert a '\0'.  It would work for the second loop though.

Comment: For all. of your criticism, at least my loop doesn't invoke undefined behaviour.  Just by looking at yours I can tell you didn't bother testing it.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, guilty as charged, thank you for you help. I've corrected and tested the lines above.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, also I didn't think I was criticizing?  I thought I was answering your "What's wrong with" comment (BTW, I stated a number of times that nothing was wrong)?  I'm sorry if I've offended you.